# How to extract miliseconds from timestamp dynamically in postgres plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to get milliseconds from a 'Timestamp with timezone' using a plsql function.
I am able to generate the following function, but it is leading to truncation of miliseconds.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION getMSFromTime(t1 timestamp with time zone) 
        RETURNS bigint AS $$
        declare time1 double precision ;
        BEGIN
        SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t1) into time1;
        return time1;
        END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but it ignores miliseconds

```
SELECT getMSFromTime('2019-02-11 08:01:33.423+00') //1549872093
SELECT getMSFromTime('2019-02-11 08:01:33.000+00') //1549872093
```

I am able to get a PostgreSQL way so that millisecond decimals are preserved as well, using:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2019-02-11 08:01:33.423+00'); // 1549872093.423
```

But I am not able to integrate it into a function and it gives following error:

```
 syntax error at or near "t1"
LINE 5: ...ELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE t1) into t..


CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION getMSFromTime2(t1 timestamp with time zone) 
        RETURNS bigint AS $$
        declare time1 double precision ;
        BEGIN
        SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE t1) into time1;
        return time1;
        END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Please suggest a way so as to create a PostgreSQL function which can do this functionality.

Comment: The issue is that your second function needs only to write `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t1)` the declaration of timestamp with time zone is unnecessary and breaks the syntax.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/how-to-get-the-timestamp-column-in-only-milliseconds-from-postgresql

Comment: also your function should not return a bigint, as it would truncate the decimals (i.e. the milliseconds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extract()` returns a double value that represents **seconds**, by casting that to a bigint you lose the fractional seconds (=milliseconds)

If you want a bigint representing milliseconds, you need to multiple the result with 1000.

There is also no reason to use PL/pgSQL for such a simple thing:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION getmsfromtime(t1 timestamp with time zone) 
  RETURNS bigint
AS $$
  SELECT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM t1)*1000)::bigint;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```